# sqllite сортировка по адресу

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

в БД(**SQL-Lite**) есть поле адрес (тип поля text)

Например:

```
468464, Москва, Ленина, 14, 1
468464, Москва, Ленина, 14, 2
468464, Москва, Ленина, 14, 3
468464, Москва, Ленина, 14, 10
468464, Москва, Ленина, д.14, кв12
468464, Москва, Ленина, д, 14, 13 кв
```

Правильный порядок:

```
ул, 14, 1
ул, 14, 2
ул, 14, 3
ул, 14, 10
ул, 14, 20
```

а на деле получается так:

```
ул, 14, 1
ул, 14, 10
ул, 14, 2
ул, 14, 20
ул, 14, 3
```

Т.е. просто **order by addressColumn** не работает. Как можно решить эту проблему?

*UP

Возможно ли sql запросом из строки **468464**, Москва, Ленина, д, **14**, **13** кв оставить только цифры? 4684641413

Comment: Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4939580/3069565), если шаблон адреса всегда одинаковый.

Comment: боюсь придется адрес разбирать на компоненты и возможно было бы правильнее изначально хранить его в разных полях по компонентам

Comment: к сожалению шаблон адреса может быть разный т.к. в основную базу писали как попало.

И разбирать по компонентам тоже не известно как т.к. нет четкого шаблона адреса.

А нету другой возможность?

Comment: ну тогда это вообще не разрешимая задача. можно конечно попробовать тупо выделить последнее число строки, дополнить его нулями слева и так сортировать. но у вас потом начнутся проблемы с номерами домов, их то же захочется сортировать в числовом порядке. Так что лучше было бы сделать внешний скрипт, который пройдется по БД, разберет все возможные форматы и разложит это в структурированном виде по отдельным полям

Comment: спасибо за совет.

Comment: Возможно ли sql запросом из строки 468464, Москва, Ленина, д, 14, 13 кв оставить только цифры? 4684641413

Comment: Смотрите вот тут на английском 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189511/sort-numbers-and-numbersletters-with-sqlite

Answer (score 2):

Добавте несколько новых полей. Занесите в них информацию из поля с общим адресом, разбив его на компоненты. Создайте по этим новым полям композитный индекс.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ответ, чтобы он более развёрнутым. По возможности дайте пример разбивки на компоненты.